# a crash on iOS9.1

Tags: crash, ios9.1

there is a accidental crash on iOS9.1(iOS8 or iOS7 is find,and it doesn't reappear in my device)

It happended frequently when our custom keyboard show up. Here is the crash log, I don't know what does it mean.

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019a971bd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1 UIKit 0x000000018b874e60 -[UITouch .cxx_destruct] + 136
2 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019a95eb54 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
3 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019a96a080 objc_destructInstance + 92
4 libobjc.A.dylib 0x000000019a96a0e0 object_dispose + 28
5 UIKit 0x000000018b46a52c -[UITouch dealloc] + 72
6 CoreFoundation 0x0000000185ed1c74 ___CFBasicHashDrain + 276
7 CoreFoundation 0x0000000185d8a19c CFDictionaryRemoveAllValues + 340
8 UIKit 0x000000018b86eb40 -[UITouchesEvent _setHIDEvent:] + 136
9 UIKit 0x000000018b42e164 __UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 3984
10 CoreFoundation 0x0000000185e54544 ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
11 CoreFoundation 0x0000000185e53fd8 ___CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
12 CoreFoundation 0x0000000185e51cd8 ___CFRunLoopRun + 724
13 CoreFoundation 0x0000000185d80ca0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
14 GraphicsServices 0x0000000190fbc088 GSEventRunModal + 172
15 UIKit 0x000000018b498ffc UIApplicationMain + 192
16 MyApp 0x0000000100441088 main (main.m:59)
17 libdyld.dylib 0x000000019b1ae8b8 _start + 4
SEGV_ACCERR
```

And here is the last event before app crashed.

```
< 0x14e8887f0,UICompatibilityInputViewController >,ViewDidAppear
< 0x14c9fd200,UIInputWindowController >,ViewDidAppear
< 0x14e89f650,UICompatibilityInputViewController >,ViewDidAppear
< 0x14c9fd200,UIInputWindowController >,ViewDidLoad
< 0x14d255a00,UIMyViewController >,ViewDidAppear,  --->our vc,which needs user's input
```

Comment: Did you try to set an exception breakpoint, and view the logs?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner thanks for reply. It doesn't reappear in my device, so I can't debug

Comment: Exactly the same crash here, have no access to device either (saw it on Crashlytics). iOS 9.3.2, iPad Air 2.